# Handle collisions in separate class

Tags: c++, file, class, collision, sfml

I am currently coding for the Ludum Dare I need to be able to handle collisions from a top-down perspective. I know how to handle them normally, but I am going to be including a lot of things that can be run into, so I would like to handle collisions from a bool return in a separate class. The way I would do it is give the function the input rectangle for the player collision box and then store all of the collisions in the function. However if I do it that way then I will have to check every single time I move if I run into something. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, especially if you are making a game for Ludum Dare, there's nothing wrong with checking collisions naively (iterating over every object and asking "Am I colliding with this?") because your game will likely be small and you have plenty of processor power to spare.

With that said, it's extremely inefficient. There are two ways to improve this, and they are often implemented together:

1. Quad trees, or some other form of collision optimization, should be used. This recursively splits the game world into quadrants, each with a specified number of entities inside of each quadrant. This means that your character is only checking collision with a small handful of entities rather than all of them.
2. You really need an event system. Judging by your question, you are a beginner at game development. That's perfectly okay, but iterating over each entity is just a gross waste of computing power. With an event system (you can learn about them anywhere on the internet, and they have been implemented countless times in SFML), the game is "notified" when a collision occurs, rather than "waiting for it."

Again, both techniques are advanced, but it comes with the territory in the wonderfully fun and harsh world of game development. Godspeed.